# Bookmarklet for mobile browser including login info

Tags: authentication, bookmarklet, mobile-browser

Our website FavSync is a bookmarks manager and we're trying to achieve the following:

On the mobile version of our website (there's no mobile app, just a mobile version) we would like to allow users to add bookmarks to their FavSync page on the go (adding the website they currently have open).

On the PC browsers we achieved that by creating extensions/add-ons for each browser. 
However, not all mobile browsers support extensions and it would be too much work to create one for each mobile browser, therefore we are thinking of a boomkarklet.

Two questions:

1. We are looking into the direction of a bookmarklet: Every user will have a different URL, including their login info and store it as a bookmark in their mobile browser. Does someone have experience with this in mobile devices? Can this work?
2. Any other solution/idea you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

The bookmarklet will work, but it will have to be run in a separate window in order to be persistent. Here are some examples:

- [Creating Window remotes using the window.opener property](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/remote2.shtml)
- [Window Spawning and Remotes](http://www.webreference.com/js/column7/attributes.html)
- [Creating a remote control bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/remotecontrol.html)
- [Cross-Document Messaging and RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/ff800814.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, we will check into this direction