# How to make a bookmarklet that executes functions in multiple pages without clicking again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, bookmarklet

I am trying to run a JavaScript's code snippet from a bookmarklet.

My intention is to automate clicks and fill text boxes in order to simulate a journey through multiple pages.

Make it happening in a single page is easy, but when the first page redirects to the next one the script stops executing functions on the next page.

The code that I am using is this:

`javascript:(function(){
    $(“#textbox").select(),
    $(“#textbox").val(“my-value").change(),
    $(“.go-to-next-page").click(),
    setTimeout(function(){doThingsOnSecondPage()},2000);
})();`

But it seems to stop as soon as the next page is requested.

Comment: Second page is on same website/domain?
If it is on different domain, it would be impossible to access it without clicking bookmarklet again. (due to Same Origin Policy)

Comment: Yes, the second page is on the same website.

Comment: The first page is where I input the details and the second is the results page (where I need to do something more).

Comment: Anyway, "doThinkgsOnSecondPage()" function won't work, as you expect. After page reload/redirect, it a completely different document.
It would be worth to mention page URL where you are trying to execute bookmarklet.

Comment: I tried to call window.location(url of the second page), but it won't be executed because  the script will stop before reaching that point..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bookmarklet for mobile browser including login info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975176/bookmarklet-for-mobile-browser-including-login-info)